# ros2 interface name is not multicastable

Tags: ros2, ros-galactic

I am new to ros2. When I try to run a launch file, I get this message.

selected interface "interfaceName" is not multicast-capable: disabling multicast

I get this message when I use galactic, but when I use dashing I'm not getting this error.

Is there a possibility to disable this message?

Environment
Docker image: Ubuntu20
Ros2 Distro: galactic

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why is the message a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but I suspect the message is coming from the RMW implementation. The default RWM implementation for Galactic (`rmw_cyclonedds`) is different from the default in Dashing (`rmw_fastrtps_cpp`). You could try setting the environment variable `RMW_IMPLEMENTATION` to try a different RMW before launching, e.g.:

```
export RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_fastrtps_cpp
```

Note, this changes the underlying communication library; you should set this variable in all terminals that are starting ROS nodes, otherwise you may run into issues with nodes communicating with each other. For more details about changing the RMW, see [Working with multiple ROS 2 middleware implementations](https://docs.ros.org/en/galactic/How-To-Guides/Working-with-multiple-RMW-implementations.html).